# dropwizard multiple tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dropwizard

How would I create two tables in a single database in dropwizard?

In my run method I have:

```
public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    final PersonDAO dao = new PersonDAO(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
    final LADAO dao2 = new LADAO(hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
    environment.jersey().register(new ProtectedResource());
    environment.jersey().register(new PeopleResource(dao));
    environment.jersey().register(new PersonResource(dao));
    environment.jersey().register(new LAResource(dao2));}
```

Comment: You can like, just do it? :) Your run method does not create any tables here. What is that you have issues with specifically? Hibernate does not necessarily create tables for you, unless you tell it to

Answer (score 0):

Tables are created in your migrations.xml file

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="people">
        <!-- first table created -->
        <createTable tableName="table1">
            <column name="jobTitle" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>
        <!-- second table created -->
        <createTable tableName="table2">
            <column name="whatever" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Then use the 'db migrate' command to run the migration:

```
java -jar hello-world.jar db migrate helloworld.yml
```